# Not able to set location of JLabel on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have set location (0,0) for the JLabel with respect to the JPanel. But it is appering at the center and top. What mistake am I making ?

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Main extends JFrame 
{ 
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel label1;
public Main() 
{ 
    panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 

    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("3.png"); 
    label1 = new JLabel(icon1); 
    label1.setLocation(0,0); 
    panel.add(label1);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    this.setSize(500,500); 
    this.setVisible(true); 

} 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Main(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: there is absolutely no way around learning all about LayoutManagers, f.i. in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: +1 for the SSCCE.  It made it easier to jump in quickly and help support the right answer (with a screenshot ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the layout manager to `null` didn't work for me.  Try this:

```
// setLocation(0,0); //remove line.
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)); // change from 'centered'
```

Voila! :) I recommend you look into the new `RelativeLayout` manager.

Comment: Isn't flowlayout default for jpanel ? THen why do I need to set it again ?

Comment: @JohnWatson: yes, it is, and no, you don't.

Comment: The default FlowLayout is center aligned.  Note the argument passed to the constructor above which sets it to left aligned.

Comment: @AndrewThompson what if i need the image to follow the mouse, what layout should be used ?

Comment: *"..need the image to follow the mouse"*  Custom painting.  Layout (or lack of it) is irrelevant.  Ask a separate question and I'll show how you could combine a custom painted BG image that follows the mouse, with components that are laid out on top of it.

Answer (score 9):

## Use Layouts!

[image: Screenshot of left aligned image icon]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label1;

    public Main() throws Exception
    {
        // Do use layouts (with padding & borders where needed)!
        panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif");
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(url);

        label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
        // Don't use null layouts, setLocation or setBounds!
        //label1.setLocation(0,0);
        panel.add(label1);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(400,200);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Main();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Update

There seems to be a lot of confusion amongst replies to this thread, so to clarify one matter:

- A `JPanel` does have a `FlowLayout` by default.
- The `FlowLayout` it gets, comes from the 'no args' constructor, e.g. [`new FlowLayout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout%28%29)<sup>1</sup>.
- The no-args constructor for a `FlowLayout` produces..

  > (1) ..a new FlowLayout with a **centered alignment** and a default 5-unit horizontal and vertical gap.

Comment: why layout of panel needs to be set when by default it is flow layout ?

Comment: what about if I want the image at the center of the panel ?

Comment: 1) See the edit.  2) Use the no-args constructor (e.g. a default panel).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this because default layout manager cares about rendering of elements into your panel.

If you really want to set element on position you choose say `panel = new JPanel(null);`

But wait a moment! Do you indeed want to do this? I believe you do not. We (java programmers) typically use the service provided by layout managers to render elements on screen. You have to spend an hour to learn and understand the concept and then I promise you that you will use this technique and forget about manual rendering of elements on screen as abut a very bad dream.

Comment: Basically, I want image to follow the mouse location. Then I have to set layout to null, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the absolute location of a `Component` while its `Container` has a `LayoutManager`; you have to call `setLayout(null)` on the `JPanel` before this will work.

Comment: Or you should learn which layouts are availables here [Oracle layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Why: the LayoutManager will always overwrite the location when laying out the component contents (when the component is made visible, for example)

Comment: I suppose what he's saying, in a clumsy way, is that it'd be better to use a layout manager than absolute positioning, as in @AlexR's answer. In this particular case I just answered the question that was actually asked, but of course it's true that this isn't the best way to do things.

Comment: *"call setLayout(null) .. before this will work."*  Show me the case where a `null` layout ***does*** work (in an x-plat., x-PLAF., resizable UI).

Comment: OK, @AndrewThompson -- in a GUI builder application, where you're positioning components by dragging them around.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill : Don't they use GroupLayout for that, when you drag them and position them in GUI Builders ? Well I am not sure though, but some layout does roll at the backend. Hadn't tried any GUI BUILDER yet.

Comment: *"you're positioning components by dragging them around."*  Are you going to do that on the computer of the end user, when they change the PLAF, resize the GUI and it all falls apart?  You seem to be missing (or ignoring) the constraints I set.  See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for my further views (some unkind folk might call it a 'rant') on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

By writing

> panel = new JPanel();

you force panel to use FlowLayout which adds elements inline. You can use

> panel = new JPanel(null);

if you want gain more performance by disabling FlowLayout manager, but by doing so you'll must take care for nasty things, like components location, dimensions and so on. I think it's better to use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Please do suggest, always consider setting layout to null as the last step, which might never happen actually. Since someone behind the scenes is working hard to make layouts work for every specific need of a user. +1 for this edited info though :-)

Comment: In your profile seems like you wanted to write Computer Science Student, but had written Computer Since Student. Do rectify that If I am right :-)

Comment: LOL, sure I meant that I'm computer science student.

Answer (score 1):

```
setLayout(null); //set your frame layout to null for abs. positioning
yourPanel = new JPanel(); // create your JPanel
yourPanel.setLayout(null); // set the layout null for this JPanel !

text1 = new JLabel("SB"); // create some stuff
text2 = new JLabel("BB");

yourPanel.add(text1); // add the stuff to the JPanel
yourPanel.add(text2);
yourPanel.getComponent(0).setBounds(0,0, 20, 20); // set your position of your elements inside your JPanel
yourPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); // set a testing border to help you position the elements better
yourPanel.setBounds(30, 200, 750, 220); // set the location of the JPanel
```

//leave me a reply